# Application crashes on small screen but not in large screens

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to inflate a layout .It is working fine in larger screens. However it's not working in small screen.I got the following error on Log

It's working on nexus 7,LG .However not in Samsung Galaxy Y (2.7 inch).

```
   **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onMeasure(CustomViewAbove.java:456)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:847)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    ... 56 more
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a**
```

I am not able to find the problem.

My Layout is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.android.utils.MyTextViewHead
        android:id="@+id/card_offer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/head_left"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/CARD_OFFERS"
        android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

   <!--  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sidearea_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/side_round"
        android:padding="@dimen/sidearea_padding" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spin_l"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/searchbox"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/card_text_dfault"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" >
            </EditText>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_theme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown"
               android:entries="@array/theme_array"
                android:prompt="@string/Theme" 
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                   android:entries="@array/category_array"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown"               
                android:prompt="@string/Category" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_emirate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                   android:entries="@array/emirate_array"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown"
                android:prompt="@string/Emirate" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                   android:entries="@array/location_array"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown"               
                android:prompt="@string/Location" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_now_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_now_selecter" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout file here

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the size of the screen, but the version of API. Please post layout layout xml file.

Comment: posted phone has 2.3.6 sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its your main bug :- 
          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a**

please check you resources in your drawable folder. You are missing some resource for your small layout.

either you are using some type of widgets , which are not supporting for low version devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target in Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Comment: phone version is 2.3.6